# Check if item of a dataframe is inside another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to compare a little subset of a dataframe to check if exists in other dataframe with pandas.

For example:

**Dataframe1**

```
id     state
1111   M   
2222   A   
3333   A   
4444   M   
5555   A   
6666   M
```

**Dataframe2**

```
ids    status
8888   M   
2222   A   
3333   A   
4444   M   
5555   C   
6666   M
```

As you can see, the headers are different between these dataframes.
I would like get the each row of Dataframe1, and check if both columns (id and state) exists in Dataframe2, in its corresponding columns (id -> ids, state -> status)

I'm starting with pandas right now, so i'm so sorry if this question has been aswered before.

I was trying with the following code, but I'm only able to compare one column, and not the rest.

```py
first_data = pandas.read_csv(first_csv, usecols=["id", "state"])
second_data = pandas.read_csv(second_csv, usecols=["ids", "status"])
print first_data["id"].isin(second_data["ids"])
```

Is this the correct method to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df1.isin(df2.rename(columns={'status': 'state', 'ids': 'id'})).all(1)`

Comment: Wow! thanks for the quick reply! It is working like a charm! To understand what you are doing there: You are comparing both dataframes but renaming the columns from the df2 to match the df1 ones right?

Comment: Another good one is to use the `indicator` argument in `merge`. It indicates if the row is in both dataframes, right_only or left_only: `df1.merge(df2, left_on=['id', 'state'], right_on=['ids', 'status'], indicator=True, how='left')`. In this case you don't need renaming.

Comment: Thanks @Erfan! I just tried and its working too. It returns another dataFrame with the `_merge` attr in it, that indicates from which df the merge comes. What is the benefits of not renaming the dataFrame. Is the renaming permanent? Thanks!